# When can you have relative URLs on the request line of GET http requests?

Tags: http, url, request

I tried the following request:

```
GET index.htm HTTP/1.1
connection: close
host: example.com
content-length: 0
```

But earned a 400 Bad Request. Why? The server should be able to piece together the absolute URL: http://example.com/index.htm . Why does it complain? Do I need a referer header to use relative URLs on the request line?

Answer (score 3):

### Short answer

You can't use relative path because HTTP specification ([RFC7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.3.1)) requires the use of absolute path.

### Explanation

If you just refer to HTTP specification, it easy to find out why your request got a `400 Bad Request` response: it violates the specification.
[RFC7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.3.1) defines that in your scenario, the request target must use what is called the origin-form that requires absolute path:

```
origin-form = absolute-path [ "?" query ]
```

For instance, the HTTP request for `http://example.org/where?q=now` would be:

```
GET /where?q=now HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
```

If the path is empty, such as `http://example.org` the HTTP request would be:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
```

This is because the absolute path is required as explained in [Section 5.3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.3.1) as follows (emphasis mine):

> When making a request directly to an origin server, other than a
> CONNECT or server-wide OPTIONS request (as detailed below), a client
> MUST send **only the absolute path and query components** of the target
> URI as the request-target.

Comment: You evidently forgot to read the question. And didn't bother to look at my solution below. I can't downvote you but this wasn't helpful.

Comment: This is actually correct. You must differenciate between absolute paths and absolute URLs. This answer is simply a bit more high-level and abstract than "the path must start with a `/`."

Answer (score -1):

I think on this line `GET index.htm HTTP/1.1` is missing an 'l' on `index.html`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, but I'm afraid you're mistaken. A nonexistent file wouldn't cause a 400 Bad Request response. What's more, I know the file exists as written.

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer: If the URL on the request line isn't absolute it must be an absolute path. This means that you can omit the protocol and host name, but never any part of the path. The following worked:

```
GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
connection: close
host: example.com
content-length: 0
```

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, because you no longer have a relative path in your HTTP request-- you've made it an absolute path in your sample request above.  The correct answer is given by Rei, which is that you can't use relative paths in the request line of an HTTP request.